# Moving an Image when button pressed for a certain duration

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to do a simple animation but I am having trouble finding what I'm looking for online.

I want the user to hit a button which will thus translate a UIImageView (clouds01) from one point to another, starting in the upper left hand corner and ending in the dead center of the screen.

All of the tutorials I have seen either just move the image once per tap or move the image in a direction infinitely.

I followed a tutorial online that uses NSTimer to repeat a translate method, but it does it infinitely, like shown here. It just keeps moving the image 16 x 12 every .033 seconds, but I want it to stop in the middle.

```
- (IBAction)animateClouds:(UIButton *)sender {

cloud01.center = CGPointMake(-512, -384);// sets cloud initial position
cloudTimer01 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.033 target:self       selector:@selector(moveCloud01) userInfo:nil repeats:1];

if (cloudTimer01 == nil) {
        cloudTimer01 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.033 target:self selector:@selector(moveCloud01) userInfo:nil repeats:1];
}

-(void)moveCloud01{
cloud01.center = CGPointMake(cloud01.center.x + 16, cloud01.center.y + 12);
}
```

Any ideas of what to do to make it stop? Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: "`Moving an Image when button pressed for a certain duration`" vs. "`I want the user to hit a button`". These are contradicting statements. Kindly elaborate on the behavior you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just **invalidate** the timer when the cloud is close enough to the center.

```
- (void)moveCloud01
{
    cloud01.center = CGPointMake(cloud01.center.x + 16, cloud01.center.y + 12);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourCenterRect, cloud01.center))
    {
        [cloudTimer01 invalidate];
    }
}
```

`yourCenterRect` is a `CGRect` that indicates the center area. When the cloud's center is in this area you simply stop the timer.